# Where does the FBI get all its NZT?

Tags: plot-explanation, limitless-tv

I'm on episode 4 of the Limitless TV series. How is it that the FBI has an apparently "limitless" supply of NZT? Is it explained in the early episodes?  (I've been told it's explained in the later episodes, so I'm looking for an earlier explanation.)

In the pilot, people are killing each other for small numbers of pills, so presumably its street value is enormous.

Comment: No official statement available on this and googling doesn't did help at all.. There was a similar question on [SciFi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121482/how-does-the-fbi-supply-nzt-for-brian), which is the better I could found at the moment. You can read it there. and this article on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/limitless/comments/3qj7e5/fbis_supply_of_pills/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first episode, Naz gives the back story on the FBI's involvement with NZT.  She mentions in passing that the FBI has reverse engineered the drug.  The implication is that they are able to manufacture it in house, or out of house (she does not specify.)

Brian Finch is the first opportunity they've had to actually continue tests with the drug, as he is immune to the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Episode 11 of the series explicitly shows where the FBI gets the NZT.  They purchase it from a pharmaceutical company that operates a high-security pharmacy.

Answer (score 0):

The pilot episode mentions some experiments with NZT, and we see photos of the terrible side effects it had on the subjects. Presumably FBI has the pills from the same source as that of the experiments.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it is actually being clarified in the later episodes.

However, you could - for additional information and entertainment - watch the movie also called [Limitless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limitless_(film)) - it is kind of a prequel for the tv show in the way that the movie starts exactly where the tv shows ends.

Comment: *"it is actually being clarified in the later episodes"* - Can you elaborate *how* it is clarified to flesh this out into a proper answer a little more? (Provided it adds to the existing answers.)